# Python Dispatch Table String Variables

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dispatch

I need to use a string to determine which calculation to run. I am trying to use a dispatch table instead of an elif ladder. I need to run some one liners, some multi-line functions, and I need to run a function based on a portion a an incoming state.

This code is simplified to explain. The first 4 functions work but the last 3 do not.

```
<!-- language: python -->
Fun = functions.get(reference, lambda : print('Invalid Ref'))
fun(my_df, start, stop)

def Ripple(df, start, stop):#Some multi-line function
    temp = df.trc3_s12_db[df.index >= start, df.index <= stop]
    return temp.values.max() - temp.values.min()

def RAve(df, start, stop, ave, spacing=100):#Changing function
    return df.trc3_s12_db.rolling(ave*spacing).[df.index >= start, df.index <= stop].min()

functions = { #Dispatch Table
    'MinA': lambda df, start, stop: df[df.index >= start, df.index <= stop].tA.min() * (-1),
    'MaxA': lambda df, start, stop: df[df.index >= start, df.index <= stop].tA.max() * (-1),
    'MinB': lambda df, start, stop: df[df.index >= start, df.index <= stop].tB.min() * (-1),
    'Ripple': Ripple,
    '5MHz Ave': RAve(ave=5),
    '2.2MHz Ave': RAve(ave=2.2),
    '%dMHz Ave': RAve(ave=%d) #Is this possible?
}
```

I know I can pass functions and arguments using a tuple but then the whole table needs to be a tuple.

Can I pass variables through the formatting of a string into a dispatch table?
What is the best way to sort through these possibilities?

Comment: Edited to clarify. I want to pass the same dataframe, start, and stop and then the window for rolling()

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a "partial function": https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: `functools.partial(RAve, ave=5)` gives a callable with `ave` asigned to 2.2 in the call

Comment: without specifying the variable (5 instead of ave=5), does it pass the 5 to the first variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, it looks like you're trying to create a partial function, a function made of anotherfunction with some of it's arguments 'burned in'.

For the second part `'%dMHz Ave': RAve(ave=%d) #Is this possible?` - no, this isn't possible. You'd need some other logic to detect this case, and then use something other than the dispatch table (dict) in that case. E.g. Use a regexp to check if the expression matches `"xxxMHz Ave"` and in that case to use `RAve(ave=xxx)`m

Comment: Are partial function and regexp both libraries? Are there any 'vanilla' ways to handle this? Can I nest dispatch tables? This is my first time using a dispatch table in python.

Comment: Partial functions are built into python via the `functools` package docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial.

Comment: Some good regex links https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp